# Prove that any linear operator on a finite dimensional inner product space , there exists a unique linear operator

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Prove that for every linear operator $T$ on a finite dimensional inner product space $V$, there exists a unique linear operator $T^*$ on $V$ such that
$\langle T\alpha,\beta\rangle=\langle\alpha,T^*\beta\rangle$ for every $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in $V$.

Thanks for your time!O(∩_∩)O~

Comment: Hint: Given an operator T, and an *** orthonormal *** basis $e_*$, then $<T e_i, e_j>$ will determine the coefficients of the matrix representing $T$ in the basis $e_*$. Hint: For $v = \Sigma_{i = 1, \ldots, n} a_i e_i$, then $<v, e_i> = a_i$.

Comment: Another approach: Consider the map $\phi$ from $V \to V^*$ given by $\beta \mapsto \langle \cdot , \beta \rangle$. This is an isomorphism since it is injective and since $V, V^*$ have same dimension. Let $T^t:V^* \to V^*$ denote the canonical adjoint of $T$. Then define $T^* := \phi^{-1} \circ T^t \circ \phi$ and check it has the desired properties.

Answer (score 1):

To find $T^*$, we can build a map $\phi :\alpha \rightarrow <T\alpha, \beta>$. It is a linear function. Because T is a linear operator and V is a finite dimension inner product space, there exists a unique ${\beta}^{'}$, s.t. $<T\alpha, \beta>=<\alpha, {\beta}^{'}>$ for all $\alpha$. So we find $T^*(\beta)={\beta}^{'}$

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've seen this proved before.
Let $y \in V$. Define a function $h_y: V \rightarrow F$ by $$h_y(x) = \langle T(x),y \rangle.$$ Then for $x_1, x_2 \in V$ and $a \in F$, we have
\begin{align}
h_y(ax_1 + x_2) &= \langle T(ax_1 + x_2), y \rangle \\ 
&= a \langle T(x_1), y \rangle + \langle T(x_2),y \rangle \\
&= a h_y(x_1) + h_y(x_2),
\end{align}
so our function $h_y$ is linear for all $y$. There's a theorem (6.8 from Friedberg, Insel and Spence Linear Algebra) that tells us there exists a unique vector $y' \in V$ such that
$$\langle T(x), y \rangle = \langle x, y' \rangle \; \forall x \in V.$$
Now define $T^*: V \rightarrow V$ by $T^*(y) = y'$, and we have
$$\langle T(x), y \rangle = \langle x, T^*(y) \rangle \; \forall x,y \in V.$$